# How to open a link in the same page

Tags: django, python-3.x

Once I click on the link it opens in different page, I want to open it in 
the same html page. Following is the code:

**view.py:**

```
def index(request):
all_client = Clients.objects.all()
return render(request,'update/index.html',{'all_client' : all_client})

def detail(request,album_id):

client = get_object_or_404(Clients,pk=album_id)
return render(request,'update/detail.html',{'client' : client})
```

**index.html:**

```
    <body>

    <main>
        <nav id="nav">
        <div class="innertube">
            {% if all_client%}
                <h3> All the clients</h3>
                <ul>
                {% for client in all_client %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'update:detail' client.id %}" 
  target="MainWindow">{{client.client_name}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% else %}
                <h3> There is no such client</h3>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </main>
    <div class = "middle">

    </div>

</body>
```

**update/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
 # /music/
 url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
 # /music/71/
 url(r'^(?P<client_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name='detail'),
 ]
```

The page is `detail.html` which I want to load in `index.html`
[image]

Comment: You need to create base html and extend base to show whatever content you want. This way you don't loose any style of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this attribute in your `ahref` link

```
target="MainWindow"

<a href="{% url 'update:detail' client.id %}">{{client.client_name}}</a>
```

Comment: yea, i removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `base.html` template where you have 2 columns defined.
Your `index.html` should extends `base.html` (`{% extends 'base.html' %}`) and overwrite the left column with your list of clients.

When you click on a specific client, it will redirect to detail which will extends from `index.html` and overwrite the right column with the specific things you want to display!

Don't forget to still pass your variables (list of clients) in `views.detail` as well as the specific client.

When you click again, it should juste change the page and display the new client.

Hope it works for you!